# Disable SharePoint 2013 Workflow Trigger when updating list item via CSOM

Tags: csom, updatelistitems, workflow-manager

I have multiple lists in my SharePoint application that have workflows attached to them. These workflows trigger when list items are updated, which when updated from the SharePoint UI is the intended behavior.

I have a use case where I need to update items in one of these lists during a nightly ETL process using the .NET CSOM. The user that is executing the process does not resolve to a single user account inside of the User Profile Services, so Workflow Manager suspends the workflow instance.

I've explored the possibility of defining alternative credentials as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382583/use-credentials-to-interact-with-the-client-object-model-of-sharepoint) so that the Workflow can resolve a user from UPS, but I don't like the idea of hardcoding a password in code (even if it's read from a config file) due to the maintenance risk.

I've also explored the configuration of the user profile services to not bring in those accounts that are causing the conflict, but I don't have control over my domain and thus, would also become a maintenance nightmare.

Does anyone know of a method that exists programmatically to disable the triggering of workflows from the CSOM?

Comment: I don't know of anything in the CSOM, if you could convert it to SSOM, then there should be possibilities like systemupdates or disableeventfiring perhaps.

Comment: Unfortunately, my ETL process runs on a separate server from SharePoint so there would be additional overhead to using the SSOM. Plus, I don't think the SSOM supports the disabling of SharePoint 2013 workflows...